# How to put checkbox in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am making a simple Note Maker using Ionic 4. I am stuck at putting CHECK BOX near my Ionic Label. But when i click to the checkbox it takes me to the another page where i can edit that particular post. But i want to just select that checkboxes and then want to implement multiple delete.

[Screen Shot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksyqQ.png)

```
            <ion-header>
              <ion-toolbar color="#ffbd00">
                <ion-title color="light">
                  Notes
                </ion-title>
                <ion-buttons slot="end">
                  <ion-button (click)="addNote()">
                    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add" color="light"></ion-icon>
                  </ion-button>
                </ion-buttons>
              </ion-toolbar>
            </ion-header>

            <ion-content>
              <ion-grid>
                 <ion-row *ngFor="let note of notesService.notes">
                   <ion-col col-12>
                    <ion-list no-lines>
                      <ion-item-sliding>
                      <ion-list>
                        <ion-item button detail  [href]="'/notes/' + note.id" routerDirection="forward" color="#810000">
                        <ion-label>{{ note.title }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-checkbox slot="end"></ion-checkbox>
                        </ion-item>
                      </ion-list>
                    </ion-item-sliding>
                    </ion-list>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
              </ion-grid>
            </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are putting href to your `ion-item`

```
 <ion-item button detail  [href]="'/notes/' + note.id" routerDirection="forward" color="#810000">
```

and your checkbox is placed inside the ion-item, so clicking on checkbox propagates click to item also.

There 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Instead of using href to ion-item try using it for ion-label, may be direct href if it works or by enclosing ion-label in an  tag.
2. Using event stopPrapagation.

To know about event propagation follow this link.
http://logic24by7.com/angularjs-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault/